# Call a WCF service protected by ACS, which uses ADFS as IDP

Tags: wcf, saml, claims-based-identity, acs, adfs2.0

[Following this post](http://bit.ly/VNwCwk) I have created a WCF client which:

1. Uses ADFS to authenticate users against AD.
2. Provides a SAML2 ticket to the caller.
3. Uses the supplied SAML2 ticket to call the WCF Service.

This is working great, however the next part of my problem is to extend this to use Azure ACS.

I added the RP to ACS, and changed the STS reference to point to ACS using `Add STS Reference` in Visual studio.

I have extended the `Token.GetToken` method, supplying the token into the following method:

```
public static SecurityToken GetToken(SecurityToken adfsToken, string appliesTo, string idpEndpointAddress, out RequestSecurityTokenResponse rsts)
{
    WS2007HttpBinding binding = new WS2007HttpBinding();
    binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
    binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;

    WSTrustChannelFactory trustChannelFactory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(binding, new EndpointAddress(idpEndpointAddress));
    trustChannelFactory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
    trustChannelFactory.ConfigureChannelFactory();

    // Create issuance issuance and get security token 
    RequestSecurityToken requestToken = new RequestSecurityToken(WSTrust13Constants.RequestTypes.Issue);
    requestToken.AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress(appliesTo);
    WSTrustChannel tokenClient = (WSTrustChannel)trustChannelFactory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(adfsToken);
    SecurityToken token = tokenClient.Issue(requestToken, out rsts);
    return token;
}
```

To the following endpoint:

```
https://test.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/wstrust/13/issuedtoken-symmetric
```

But I get the following exception:

> Secure channel cannot be opened because security negotiation with the
>   remote endpoint has failed. This may be due to absent or incorrectly
>   specified EndpointIdentity in the EndpointAddress used to create the
>   channel. Please verify the EndpointIdentity specified or implied by
>   the EndpointAddress correctly identifies the remote endpoint.

With an inner exception of:

> ACS10001: An error occurred while processing the SOAP header.

1. What do I need to configure in ACS to get this working with the token supplied by ADFS?
2. Do I need to use the token supplied by ACS, or can I use the one supplied by ADFS in the service? (It appears to be working..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [linked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh127796.aspx) ACS sample, which seems to be doing exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks Oren - I will have a look at that example.